# Pre-purchase questions for getorgchart

Tags: getorgchart

I want to buy this chart,before it ,I have three questions.
1、what's all diff between professional、premium and enterprise ?
2、Is chart node search supported for chinese?
3、Can I use it on a LAN，no internet?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. **professional** license is for one domain or IP, **premium** 10 domains or IPs, **enterprise** unlimited domains or IPs plus source code. Also you can request custom features.
2. GetOrgChart does support Chinese. Here is an example: http://www.getorgchart.com/Experimental/ChineseLanguage.html
3. Yes you can use the product on LAN network

Comment: How can I draw the first node?finally,How can I get the whole chart json